# How to create/modify the controller class generated by pylons?

Tags: python, pylons

Say I wanted to add some imports to the file generated when I run:

```
paster controller controllern_name
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Take a look on Paster templates, is how Pylons do. To have an ideia, get source and look setup.py, commands.py and template file (controller.py_tmpl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to modify the pylons templates -- in this case `controller.py_tmpl`. It's best to create your own set of templates based on the ones from pylons, and then use them when starting a new project.

Comment: Don't change the pylons default temaplate, you can use py_tmpl as base to others...